# Kotlin Android Jetpack Navigation between Fragments in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I have a small app. 1 Activity (MainActivity.kt) and two Fragments (MainFragment & CreateNewJobFragment).

Mainfragment has a Recyclerview. CreateNewJobFragment contains a 6 spinners and an edittext. I'm attempting to have the selections from the spinners and edittext to populate the RecyclerView when the user makes their choices and clicks a "create job" button.

The issue is, when this button is clicked, the app will go back up the backstack to the MainFragment, but instead of populating the recyclerview with a new item, it runs through onCreate again and nothing happens.

**MainFragment.kt**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() ,ItemClickedCustomListener{
override fun onCustomSpinnerItemSelected(selectedItems: JobData) {

    Log.v("MainFragment","onCustomSpinnerItemSelected")
    Log.v("MainFragment","selectedItems --> "
            + selectedItems.companyName + " "
            + selectedItems.location + " "
            + selectedItems.pumpTruck + " "
            + selectedItems.smartPiggers)
    jobs.add(selectedItems)
    adapter = recyclerView.adapter as JobAdapter
    adapter.data(jobs)
}

var jobs = ArrayList<JobData>()
lateinit var  adapter : JobAdapter

private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding
lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater)
            //getting recyclerview from xml and binding it
            recyclerView = binding.jobRecyclerView

            //adding a layoutmanager
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

            //Arraylist to store jobs using the data class JobData.
            // TODO: Change this to a user created list from CreateNewJobFragment.kt
            jobs = ArrayList()

            Log.v("MainFragment", "onCreateView --> ")

            //creating adapter
            adapter = JobAdapter(jobs)

            //add adapter to recyclerView
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter

            //Setting onClickListener for FAB(floating action button) using Navigation
            binding.createNewJobFAB.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
                v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_createNewJobFragment)
            }
        }
    return binding.root
}
```

}

**CreateNewJobFragment.kt**

```
class CreateNewJobFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentCreateNewJobBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentCreateNewJobBinding.inflate(inflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    var addJobToRecyclerview = JobData("","","","")


    //String array.
    //TODO: Move this to res/strings
    val companyNames = arrayOf("Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D", "Company E")

    var nameSpinner = binding.spinnerCustomerName

    //Adapter for spinner
    nameSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, companyNames)

    //item selected listener for spinner
    nameSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("not implemented yet")
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            //user selected spinner choice added
            addJobToRecyclerview.companyName = companyNames[p2]
        }
    }

    //String array.
    //TODO: Move this to res/strings
    val refineryTown = arrayOf("Long Beach", "Houston", "Cherry Point", "Wood River", "Bismark")

    var townSpinner = binding.spinnerLocation

    //Adapter for spinner
    townSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, refineryTown)

    //item selected listener for spinner
    townSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("not implemented yet")
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            addJobToRecyclerview.location = refineryTown[p2]
        }
    }

    <SNIP>Cutting out 5 repeated spinners and editText to save some space</SNIP>


    //Setting onClickListener for 'Create Job' button using Navigation
    binding.buttonCreateJob.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
        (activity as MainActivity).itemClickedCustomListener.onCustomSpinnerItemSelected(addJobToRecyclerview)
        Log.v("CreateNewJobFragment", "Job data added -->$addJobToRecyclerview")
        Log.v("CreateNewJobFragment", "Create job button --> clicked")

        v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_createNewJobFragment_to_mainFragment)

    }

}
```

}

I'm using the following Android documentation as a guide: [Implementing Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing)

And this part in particular for the navigation back to MainFragment: [Tie destinations to UI widgets](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Tie-ui)

After clicking the "Create Job" button. App does go back to MainFragment. But as mentioned, nothing shows in Recyclerview.

I've some some logging in place. This is from the logs:

**Log sample**

> 2018-12-07 22:03:17.959 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/MainActivity: onCustomSpinnerItemSelected
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:17.959 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/MainActivity: selectedItems --> Company A Long Beach Company 1 Company 4
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:17.960 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/CreateNewJobFragment: Job data added -->JobData(companyName=Company A, location=Long Beach, pumpTruck=Company 1, smartPiggers=Company 4)
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:17.960 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/CreateNewJobFragment: Create job button --> clicked
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:18.026 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/MainFragment: onCreateView -->
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:18.146 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/JobAdapter: getItemCount 0
>
> 2018-12-07 22:03:18.146 5806-5806/com.palarran.pigtimer V/JobAdapter: getItemCount 0

As you can see, after the log entry for "Create job button --> clicked", it jumps to "onCreateView" in the MainFragment and the item count in my custom adapter(JobAdapter.kt) does not increase.

**JobAdapter.kt**

```
class JobAdapter(private var jobList: ArrayList<JobData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<JobAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

//Returning view for each item in the list
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): JobAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.job_list_item, parent, false)
    Log.v("JobAdapter","onCreateViewHolder")
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

//Binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.v("JobAdapter","onBindViewHolder")
    holder.bindItems(jobList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Log.v("JobAdapter","getItemCount " + jobList.size)
    return jobList.size
}

fun data(jobs: ArrayList<JobData>) {
    Log.v("JobAdapter","DataSetChanged")
    jobList = jobs
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

//Class holds the job list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(job: JobData) {
        val textViewCompanyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName) as TextView
        val textViewLocation  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_job_location) as TextView

        textViewCompanyName.text = job.companyName
        Log.v("JobAdapter", "bindItems" + textViewCompanyName.text)
        textViewLocation.text = job.location
        Log.v("JobAdapter", "bindItems" + textViewLocation.text)
    }
}
```

}

Am I missing something in the documents or reading them incorrectly? I'm definitely misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late responding to this.

I was able to get this figured out. By using Sugar ORM database. Calling it in onResume() in my MainFragment.

It was a dumb question that I should have researched more before posting.